# Ionic Native File.readAsDataURL giving error code: 1 message: NOT_FOUND_ERR

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to retrieve the Data URL of a picture saved to iPhone local storage in `Ionic Native`, running on real device, not simulator.

I am using `File.readAsDataURL`

I used X-code to look into my phone's local storage and I can see the image at this location.

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/* My APP ID */Documents/www/assets/images/image.png

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { File } from 'ionic-native';

declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'get-picture',
  templateUrl: 'get-picutre.html'
})

export class GetPictureComponent {
    fs:string = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;

    constructor(
        public platform: Platform
    ) {}

    ionViewDidEnter() {
         this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            console.log("FileSystem", this.fs); //logs FileSystem file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/* My APP ID */Documents/

            File.readAsDataURL(this.fs, 'www/assets/images/image.png')
              .then((imgData) => console.log('Image Data', imgData))
              .catch((error) => console.log('error', error)); //Logs error {"code":1,"message":"NOT_FOUND_ERR"}

          }); 
    }

}
```

I have tried basically the same thing with

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/* My APP ID */Documents/www/assets/images/image.png
```

and I get error code 1 again.

I updated my config.xml file with these preferences:

```
  <preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
  <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />
```

Does anyone know why this would not be working?

Ionic Version - 2.1.14

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I did a little bit more digging into this issue.

First I did a `File.listDir()` at my root documents directory `(cordova.file.documentsDirectory)`. I found that the the only folder in the documents directory, that the File System could see, was `"NoCloud"`.

Even though Wikitude is successfully putting images in a folder in this directory called `"/www/assets/images/"` the file system cannot see, write, or read to it.

I set up wikitude to save images into the "NoCloud" folder and now I can successfully use `File.readAsDataUrl()`to get base64 image data from the "NoCloud" folder.

Hope this helps someone.